# VS2012 Error while trying to run project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

when i try to run an application i've created using VS2012 it gives me an "Error while trying to run project: Could not load file or assembly".

And ive try to look on the vs log fuslogvw. This log report was given to me. I really dont know whats wrong on my VS2012.

---

```
The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80131018. No description available.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Users\acer\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication3.vshost.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = TARDIS\acer
LOG: DisplayName = WindowsFormsApplication3
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: WindowsFormsApplication3 | Domain ID: 1
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/acer/documents/visual studio 2012/Projects/WindowsFormsApplication3/WindowsFormsApplication3/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = WindowsFormsApplication3.vshost.exe
Calling assembly : Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\acer\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication3.vshost.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/acer/documents/visual studio 2012/Projects/WindowsFormsApplication3/WindowsFormsApplication3/bin/Debug/WindowsFormsApplication3.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/acer/documents/visual studio 2012/Projects/WindowsFormsApplication3/WindowsFormsApplication3/bin/Debug/WindowsFormsApplication3/WindowsFormsApplication3.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/acer/documents/visual studio 2012/Projects/WindowsFormsApplication3/WindowsFormsApplication3/bin/Debug/WindowsFormsApplication3.EXE.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Users\acer\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication3.exe
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
ERR: Error extracting manifest import from file (hr = 0x80131018).
ERR: Run-from-source setup phase failed with hr = 0x80131018.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131018). Probing terminated.
```

Comment: Check if your executable is being used by another program.

Comment: the only thing that is running is Visual Studio 2012